# Shopify - Override Quanity Pricing

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have a helicopter tour company that wants to use Shopify to sell their tours however they have some unique options for thier pricing.

- 1-2 people (same price) $x 3 people
- add $120 to $x 4/5/6 people
- add q/w/e to $x

How can I manipulate the price based on quanity. I've looked into volumn based discount apps but problem with these is that it applies a discount code. If if I added 2, it would show 50% off.

Not using Shopify plus, so no access to the script editor.

Comment: Use apps like Infinite Options from [shopPad](https://apps.shopify.com/custom-options). which allows you to add addons to a product with custom pricing.

Comment: This is a Free APP called [Product Option, Variant Option](https://apps.shopify.com/product-options-pro), which is used for the same purpose. you can go with it also.

Answer (score 0):

You really do not need any custom App or other problematic install for this. You get 100 options for prices. There are zero helicopters in 2022 that fly more than 100 people. Therefore, you can arguably set a variant for each number of people that wish to fly, and assign the correct price. If you are fancy, you could then tie those to the quantity selection.

In other words, vanilla Shopify will work fine for you.